# Wait for Swing ui construction completion, mirror of Swingworker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency

I need the opposite of a SwingWorker. I have a Thread that should start a complicated UI construction process, and then continue with other stuff. If any other thread should try and reference that UI though the getter, the getter should block until the UI is finished building. How about this pattern:

```
public class Standard {

    private JFrame uiFrame = null;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void makeUI() {
        Runnable onEDT = () -> {
            synchronized (lock) {
                uiFrame = new ComplexJFrameSubclass();
                uiFrame.setup(Standard.this);
                lock.notify();
            }
        };
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(onEDT);
    }

    public JFrame getUIFrame() {
        if (uiFrame == null) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return uiFrame;
    }
}
```

Comment: Display a modal JDialog, build the GUI, do the background stuff, when done, remove clear the modal dialog (from within a callback method), and display the GUI.

Comment: I'm very annoyed to find that invokeLater(onEDT); Is being called MUCH later. The event thread is reaching  getGUIFrame() before makeUI. So I don't this this approach will work all. I'll try lazy construction of the UI within getGUI() next.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what it is you're doing and why. Can you make your question much more concrete, explaining what the code is actually doing and why. Also consider posting a valid [mcve] that illustrates what you're trying to do and that we can work with.

Comment: And you're mentioning methods, `getGUIFrame()` & `getGUI()`, that we don't even see, so hard to give you any explanation for why your current code is behaving as it's behaving.

Comment: And Swing is single threaded, making this code look unnecessarily complex. Until we know more, I suspect that this is in fact an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do what I want:

```
/**
 * Example of a class starting construction of the UI on the EDT, but making 
 * that UI available through a getter, without race problems.
 * Pretend the JFrame being constructed is huge, complicated, and does a lot
 * of slow drawing stuff.
 */
public class Standard implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private JFrame uiFrame;
    private final Object _lock = new Object();

    public Standard makeUI() {
        if (uiFrame != null) {
            return this;
        }
        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            makeUISynched();
        } else {
            Runnable onEDT = () -> {
                makeUISynched();
            };
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(onEDT);
        }
        return this;
    }

    private Standard makeUISynched() {
        synchronized (_lock) {
            uiFrame = new JFrame();
            uiFrame.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
            return this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is now thread safer, if it is called before the UI is constructed,
     * It will create the UI itself, and wait for completion.
     * @return The JFrame UI.
     **/
    public final JFrame getUIFrame() {
        if (uiFrame == null) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                makeUISynched();
            } else {
                Runnable onEDT = () -> {
                    makeUISynched();
                };
                try {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(onEDT);
                } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return uiFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    }

}
```